# radare2 load register map

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m, radare2

I'm reversing some stm32f030 code I downloaded from the chip. I do understand the stm32s and arm assembly but I'm completely new to radare2.

There are many special registers e.g. 0x40021000 is RCC_CR, 0x40021004 is RCC_CFGR, 0x48000000 is GPIOA_MODER an so on. s. https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00091010-stm32f030x4x6x8xc-and-stm32f070x6xb-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Is there a way to import register definitions in some format so that the code analysis can automatically flag them? Or another way so that all referenzes to them are named?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Radare manual on symbols](https://book.rada.re/analysis/symbols.html), you can read a dwarf file.  So, you can make a dwarf with external definitions for the register at the absolute addresses and it **may** be able to use them in the disassembler of a second binary.

With bin-utils, you can merge a binary with the symbols.  Radare looks to have lots of utilities which can probably do the same thing; if it is not able to merge symbols from a separate DWARF file.. and this step is entirely un-needed.